# What is right approach of automatic deployment of Angular app? (Angular Cli, express, digital ocean droplet)

Tags: angular, express, deployment, angular-cli, dev-to-production

I'm developing an Angular app with Angular Cli. Also using express app as a backend server.
I have a BitBucket repository and a production server on DigitalOcean droplet with Ubuntu 16.04
So my project folder structure is quite simple:

```
- src - angular app sources
- server - express app
```

So when I make a production build Angular Cli compiles all the files to `server/public` folder (I've replaced the default `dist` as outDir in angular-cli.json)

I see here two ways of deploying my app to production server:

> 1) Simply push the whole project to remote repository on BitBucket
>   (excluding `server/public` - otherwise that's not the best practice,
>   right?), then clone it on my droplet, install all the dependencies,
>   create production build and run it via pm2
>
> 2) Create production build on my local machine, then copy just
>   `server` folder to droplet, install only production dependencies
>   needed for express app, and run it via pm2

I want to make this process easy and automatic with creating some script or something.

Yes, I understand that both ways are possible, but as I'm new to developing SPA, I do not have any experience and maybe can't see some hidden pros and cons of both ways.

Just for now I see the second as more correct because there won't be any extra files, dependencies installed and processes on my production server, just those which are needed for the app working. But! I haven't found any tutorial with that approach.

What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right approach is: it depends. The right approach depends on your setup/stack. The approaches you described would work, but are not automated in anyway since you're still copying files over to your droplet manually.

A better approach would be to use an automation tool such as [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) or [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/). For example, I use Travis for my personal site automated deployment. My [`.travis.yml`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/) file can be found [here](https://github.com/ciscoo/mateo.io/blob/master/.travis.yml).

What it does is:

- Execute the test npm script.
- Cache `node_modules`, for faster build times.
- Executes a deploy step if the commit was a tagged commit.

  - Before deploy, it builds the project for production.

Now I use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) since my personal website is just a static site built with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/). You'll need to orchestrate your steps to encapsulate the process of redeploying to your droplet, restarting pm2, and whatever else needs to happen to have a successful deploy.